# With statement in php

Tags: php, with-statement

I am wondering if there is something similar to javascript or VB's `with` statement but in php

The way this works, for example in VB is shown below. The two code snippets do the same effect:

```
array[index].attr1 = val1;
array[index].attr2 = val2;
array[index].attr3 = val3;
```

is equal to :

```
With(array[index])
    .attr1 = val1
    .attr2 = val2
    .attr3 = val3
End With
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly the with statement, but you can use references in your example:

```
$r = &$array[index];

$r->attr1 = val1;
$r->attr2 = val2;
$r->attr3 = val3;
```

Comment: @Hamish its ok for syntax :D

so there is no with-like-statement in php ?

Comment: @DanyKhalife: No, there is not.

Comment: hmm bummer, i think i'll create my own then :D
thanks fardjad!

Comment: @DanyKhalife No there's not, as we don't have it in many other languages. It hurts the readability and people can use more meaningful names for object references to achieve the same functionality. If you really want to shorten things, `Macros` are also useful in many cases.

Comment: oh yes, im actually taking a course that confirms what you just said but i didn't know that `with` would make things obscure, well at least not for me but im no expert yet :D (haven't made a 10K+ line project :P)
i'll look that up too, thx

Comment: @Dany Khalife: have you finally succeeded in making your own `with statement`? I would like to know how you solved this ..

Answer (score 0):

If needed with arrays as in your example, you can mimic the `with statement` by using the array_merge function:

```
$array = array(
    'index' =>  array(
                    'attr1' => 'val1',
                    'attr2' => 'val2',
                    'attr3' => 'val3'
                )                
);

var_dump( $array );

$array['index'] =   array_merge(
                        $array['index'],
                        array(
                            'attr1' => 'newval1',
                            'attr4' => 'newval4'
                        )
                    );

var_dump( $array );
```

Output:

```
array
  'index' => 
    array
      'attr1' => string 'val1' (length=4)
      'attr2' => string 'val2' (length=4)
      'attr3' => string 'val3' (length=4)
array
  'index' => 
    array
      'attr1' => string 'newval1' (length=7)
      'attr2' => string 'val2' (length=4)
      'attr3' => string 'val3' (length=4)
      'attr4' => string 'newval4' (length=7)
```