# What is with statement in php?

Tags: php, static, with-statement

I just found this in a laravel bundle that I just installed, and really have no idea what `with()` is... as it isn't declared any where

```
public static function of($query)
{
    $ins = with(new static); // What is with(new static) ?
    $ins->save_query($query);
    return $ins;
}
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109178/with-statement-in-php

Comment: I'd guess that "with" is a user-defined function defined somewhere in the code, it isn't a PHP construct

Comment: Why you think its PHP's stuff couldn’t it be from laravel?

Comment: Never saw with statement like that in PHP. Might be a user-defined function

Comment: @usman: yeah, that's the first google hit, the problem is, it's not relevant...

Comment: Your IDE should take you the function declaration by ctrl-clicking on the `with`.

Comment: Gordon: can't find that shortcut in Sublime2, you happen to know it? MarkBaker, Shiplu.mokadd: Had searched Laravel's folder for that function and came along everything but the `with()` helper existing function, as the `with()` function is declared in other classes as well (Redirect, View)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`with()` is not a statement but a user defined function in Laravel framework.

From [laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/api/function-with.html) :

```
490: /**
491:  * Short-cut for constructor method chaining.
492:  *
493:  * @param  mixed  $object
494:  * @return mixed
495:  */
496: function with($object)
497: {
498:     return $object;
499: }
```

Comment: Sidenote: This is obsolete with PHP 5.4 where you can do `(new Foo)->bar()`

Comment: Got it... I had the doubt as when searched Laravel's folder for `with(` had came along almost everything but what you just pointed out

Comment: @Gordon, +1 / thank god for php 5.4 ;-)

Answer (score 4):

First, answer to the title:

> In computer programming a statement is the smallest standalone element of an imperative programming language. A program written in such a language is formed by a sequence of one or more statements. A statement will have internal components (e.g., expressions).[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_%28computer_science%29)

Second, [`with()`](http://laravel.com/api/function-with.html) is a **user defined function**  in Laravel framework.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im a perfect answer would include what `with` does in Laravel